# UICollectionView not responding after CATransform3D

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, core-animation, catransform3d

I Have a `UIView` and inside I have `UICollectionView` with couple of images. 
`UICollectionView` responds to dragging, and I can scroll it without problem.
When I apply `CATransform3D` transformation to the `UIView` which holds the `UICollectionView` (scale transform effect like on twitter app), the `UICollectionView` stops responding to the touch, and then scrolling does not work.
I tried refreshing the `UICollectionView` after transformation is done, but nothing helps. 
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You should check what is real frame of `UICollectionView` after your transformation.

You can output frame it via debug console

or

use Xcode view debugging: after your transform, go to Xcode, and open in main menu

Debug->View Debuggin->Capture View Hierarchy

Comment: The frame is all right, the content size get's messed up, which I set back after the transformation, and everything is all right in both output and view debug, but collection view still doesn't respond to the touches

Comment: and what is your frame and contentSize before and after transformation?

Comment: for example, before transition is 640x200, after transformation is 320x200, I do reset the contentSize back to 640x200, but still doesntwork